# How to implement my own disk cache with picasso library - Android?

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso

I'm using picasso library to load images for my app. But I don't how to implement my own disk (sdcard) caching with picasso library.

Comment: Will it help if I recommend alternative to Picasso that I have worked with, is easy to setup and works both in memory and on disc and is highly configurable?

Comment: Picasso should already do disc caching for you. What does it not do that you need to accomplish with a custom disk cache?

Comment: @Bobbake4: I just want to cache the image in custom folder in sdcard.

Comment: Picasso is using OkHttp for default and it caches. To customize cache size you can use this https://gist.github.com/fada21/10655652.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Picasso uses the HTTP client for disk caching and if one is already configured it will use that instead of installing its own.

For the built-in UrlConnection the docs for installing a cache are here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html

If you are using OkHttp then you just call setCache: 
http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setCache-com.squareup.okhttp.Cache-

Comment: Hi, my pics are in the Picasso cache dir but the log says: 
Sending progress READING_FROM_CACHE 
Cache content not available or expired or disabled 

Any idea? 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

@Dax, to save files in custom cache directory using OkHttp, I would code something like this -

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
File customCacheDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/MyCache");
okHttpClient.setCache(new Cache(customCacheDirectory, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
OkHttpDownloader okHttpDownloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mainActivity).downloader(okHttpDownloader).build();
picasso.load(imageURL).into(viewHolder.image);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: seCache is not recognized ?

Comment: @umerk44 you're right, setCache() is no more supported. That snippet was from 2.x version, but in 3.x they've replaced the setters with builder pattern (See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). So in 3.x you can do something like  OkHttpClient.newBuilder().cache(cache)...