# android delete some pictures from cache Picasso

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am using Picasso to save a collection of pictures for offline viewing. Later I need to remove some pictures manually from the cache. I can delete all files from folder, but I don't need this. I need to delete 2 or 3 files from the cache. `invalidate` doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear in-memory cache in `Picasso` only per image:

```
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(imagePath);
```

Removing all cache is somewhat tricky and described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544650/2415329).

File cache is delegated to HTTP Client, so it's not possible to clear it from Picasso. For more information refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281195/2415329).