# How does Picasso caching mechanism responds to Cache-Control property and the Image Size?

Tags: android, performance, caching, memory-management, picasso

I'm trying to a load bigger size image (in some hundreds of KB's) using Picasso in Android. But it seems the image is loaded every time from internet and fails to load (or retrieve) from disk cache (if unavailable in main memory).

I think it may be due to the following problem.

- The image size is huge (100KB-300KB).
- The Cache-Control property is not defined in HTTP Response Header.

So my question is

1. Is there any limitation for image size in disk caching? What if the image size is huge and How does Picasso caching mechanism works in such cases?
2. Is it mandatory to set Cache-Control property in Response Header? How does Picasso consider this for caching mechanism?

If anything else is behind this mechanism as a reason, please explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Picasso with custom disk cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280242/using-picasso-with-custom-disk-cache)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as my question is about the Cache-Control property and it's limitation. @Buddy