# Build app with Picasso cache preloaded

Tags: android, picasso

I am wondering if there is any way to easily bundle a pre-cached folder of images by Picasso within an application.

**My reason is to populate the app with some basic information, that is accessible even if the user has no/limited internet connection for the first time opening the app.**

The `cache/picasso-cache` folder can be retrieved with `$ adb pull /data/data/com.package.name/ .`, but, unlike Realm ( https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#bundling-a-realm-with-an-app ), there seems to be no way to make Picasso be aware of it.

Possibly related: [Using Picasso with custom disk cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280242/using-picasso-with-custom-disk-cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although just using a pre-made cache would be really easy, I had second thoughts about it:

1. The cache pulled from the emulator was rather large.
2. It would suffice in my use-case to only show some thumbnails to the user when no internet was available. It could be much smaller.

My solution was:

1. Import all essential images into your drawables.
2. Try fetching the network-available / currently cached image with Picasso.
3. If this fetching returns an error, then fill the ImageView with the locally available drawable (with Picasso!)

Pitfalls I fell into:

1. Using Picasso's `.placeholder(R.drawable.id)` won't work because it will use the placeholder before loading the intended image, probably for saving resources/memory
2. Using Picasso's `.error(R.drawable.id)` almost works, but Picasso can't transform `placeholder` and `error` images the same way they do with the asynchronously loaded images. This means `.fit()`, `.centerInside()` and other transformations **won`t work**. (see https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/337)

---

Loading variable resource names was essential to me. This happens on `getThumbnail()`. I named all my images `product_thumbnail_{DB_ID}`.

```
private int getThumbnail(Integer id)
{
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    int resID = res.getIdentifier("product_thumbnail_"+ id, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    return resID;
}
```

---

Main logic inside my adapter:

```
final Context context = viewHolder.itemView.getContext();
final ImageView imageHolder = viewHolder.productImageHolder;
final int thumbnail = getThumbnail(product.getId());

if(thumbnail != 0)
{
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(product.getImageUrl())
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(imageHolder, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() { }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    useThumbnail(thumbnail, imageHolder, context);
                }
            });
}
else
{
    Picasso.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
            .load(product.getImageUrl())
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(imageHolder);
}
```

---

useThumbnail():

```
private void useThumbnail(int thumb, ImageView imageHolder, Context context)
{
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(thumb)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(imageHolder);
}
```