# Picasso doesn't cache image on disk

Tags: android, caching, picasso, disk

I have to use custom OkHttpClient so I can add headers to the image requests. The problem is Picasso won't cache any images on disk because of this. I've used `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` to check caching and I see only red indicators. When I use default OkHttpDownloader all is ok. Below is my Picasso initialization code. So does anyone encounter the same problem?

```
 public static void init(Context context) {
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(new AuthInterceptor());
        Downloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(client);
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(builder.downloader(downloader).build());
        Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    }
```

Also my image download code

```
 public static void load(final ImageView imageView, final Image image) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
                    .load(image.getUrl())
                    .resize(400, 0)
                    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                    .into(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: why are you doing this `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)` if you want memory cache

Comment: I actually don't want the memory cache, I want only disk cache.

Comment: Ah since this is happening when you change headers, you are most probably not setting the `Cache-Control` header

Comment: strangely adding 'header("Cache-Control", "max-age=600")' won't help, Picasso is still using only network

Comment: Picasso doesn't have a disk cache. It delegates to whatever HTTP client you are using for that functionality (relying on HTTP cache semantics for cache control). Because of this, the behavior you seek comes for free. Taken from Jake Wharton's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23281195/4128945

Comment: Also If you never see a blue indicator, it's likely that your remote images do not include proper cache headers to enable caching to disk, his quote

Comment: thanks, so I guess I have to switch to Glide

Comment: ill post this as answer with the link to Jake's answer

Comment: Btw why can't you set the headers yourself?

Comment: I did set them but I guess the response images do not include proper cache headers to enable caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah since this is happening when you change headers, you are most probably not setting the Cache-Control header

According to Jake wharton (One of the developer of Picasso)

> Picasso doesn't have a disk cache. It delegates to whatever HTTP
>   client you are using for that functionality (relying on HTTP cache
>   semantics for cache control). Because of this, the behavior you seek
>   comes for free

Taken from Jake Wharton's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281195/4128945)

Also,

> If you never see a blue indicator, it's likely that your remote images
>   do not include proper cache headers to enable caching to disk