# Caching in Picasso

Tags: android, caching, http-headers, picasso, okhttp

After reading several documentations, i want to clear some points

Reference: [this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/237)

1. For Picasso to cache my image into memory, do i have to enable "Cache-control" header in my response?
2. If i am using `OkHttpDownloader` with Picasso,will it still require me to enable the header?

   ```
   public Picasso getImageLoader(Context ctx) {

   Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(ctx);

   builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(ctx) {
       @Override
       protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri uri) throws IOException {
           HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(uri);

           connection.setRequestProperty("X-User",user.getUsername());
           connection.setRequestProperty("X-Token",user.getToken());

           return connection;
       }
   });
   return builder.build();
   }
   ```

3 Does disk caching work in Picasso on Android 4.3 or lower. Will it load my image from disk if the net is disconnected?

Comment: See: [question]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944773/how-to-implement-my-own-disk-cache-with-picasso-library-android
Jake Wharton's answer is correct

Comment: Check my previous answer here, hope it help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/29812708/672773][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29812708/672773

Answer (score 1):

In [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Caching is enabled by default.

and other settings you can do by this function `memoryPolicy(,)`

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[1])
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
.into(imageViewFromDisk);
```