# Caching in Picasso library

Tags: android, image, caching, http-headers, picasso

Why is my image not getting cached while using Picasso? When i switch off the internet, the same image doesnt load. I am using this to get the image

```
final Bitmap m = getImageLoader(context, user).load(uri).get();
```

where `getImageLoader()` is

```
public Picasso getImageLoader(Context ctx,final User user) {
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(ctx);

        builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(ctx) {
            @Override
            protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri uri) throws IOException {
                HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(uri);

                connection.setRequestProperty("X-User",user.getUsername());
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-Token",user.getToken());

                return connection;
            }
        });
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Does it has something to do with the HTTP headers. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058531/caching-in-picasso) is my other question regarding this.

Comment: I also want to know about caching using Picasso lib. I searched the web and found about okhttp . But I could not go beyond that :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to achieve this is to use **transform()**.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).transform(new Transformation() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            /*grab your Bitmap HERE!!*/
            //e.g. mBitmap = source;
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "";
        }
    }).into(new ImageView(context));
```

Above code is just an example. You can always change `.into(new ImageView(context))` with any `ImageView`, or use `Uri` instead of `url`.