# Clearing image in CircularImageView does not work | StackoverFlowException while setting image in CircularImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview

I am using https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView to get the picutures circular. And I want to clear the image in imageView if it is set already. NONE of the solutions work suggested @ [How to clear an ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859212/how-to-clear-an-imageview-in-android). Any help on how can I clear image if you have used CirularImageView ?

**EDIT**  **EDIT**
I thought I can try to show empty grayed view after resetting the image but as that is not working, I am editing the question to tell you the actual problem.

**Here it is:**
I am using RecyclerView to show friends. One of my friend list does not have picture for him so I tried to show default avatar which is SVG image. First time when I scrolled down to his view it show perfectly. When I scroll back to him again for second time, it throws StackOverFlow exception.

```
mDefaultUserPhoto = MrVector.inflate(

            getResources(), R

                    .drawable.vector_default_user_photo);
}

circularIV.setImageDrawable(mDefaultUserPhoto); // This is what hits for every friend when scrolled and where the StackoverFlowException occured..
```

Trace:

```
E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41965da0)  
﹕ Uncaught exception start!
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
System.err﹕ at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap$BitmapFinalizer.<init>(Bitmap.java:1644)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.<init>(Bitmap.java:152)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:903)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:880)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:847)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:327)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  

System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  View.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)   
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:330)  
/System.err﹕ at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:260)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:211)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:376)  
/System.err﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:185)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.configureBounds(ImageView.java:956)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.updateDrawable(ImageView.java:738)  
/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:431)  
/System.err﹕ at com.app.friends..adapters.FriendsAdapter.setPicture(FriendsAdapter.java:175)  
/System.err﹕ at com.app.friends..adapters.FriendsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FriendsAdapter.java:124)
```

Comment: What you mean by "clear the image in imageView if it is set already". Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: setImageBitmap(null) doesn't work?

Comment: @Chandrakanth, I mean I do not want to show any image in the view. I am using RecyclerView to show the list of friends. RecyclerView re-uses the views that were just shown and removed from screen. When it re-uses, though the new data (friend) does not have the image in it it uses the existing image which is the face of other friend. If I keep scrolling, it shows different face everytime depending on the availability. This all not necessary here but to understand the context better.

Comment: @PedroOliveira, no it did not work.

Comment: Why don't you just hide the ImageView according to my answer if there is no avatar of friend?

Comment: @guru Once check my answer

Comment: @rom4ek, I liked your answer. I can not do that unfortunately as I have to show a default avatar. I could not edit my question to add more details to understand the exact problem. As I explained above I am using RecyclerView to show friends. When friend does not have I want to show the default avatar. One of my friend list does not have picture for him so I tried to show default. First time when I scrolled down to his view it show perfectly. When I scroll back to him again, it throws StackOverFlow exception. Below is the code and exception details:
******

Comment: @rom4ek, I liked your answer. I can not do that unfortunately as I have to show a default avatar. I think I will edit the question to give you the full details of my actual problem.

Comment: @Chandra, that did not work as well.

Comment: @guru you can try this library instead. It's pretty the same, but maybe that won't cause problems that you have. https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean checkDrawable = (ImageView.getDrawable() != null);
if(checkDrawable ) {
 // imageView has image
}
else {
// no image assigned in image view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following,

```
imageview.setImageResource(0);
```

or

```
imageView.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested methods don't work because as you can see in the sources of `CircleImageView` the developer makes a validation about setted `Bitmap` in `onDraw`:

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Don't draw anything without an image
    if(image == null)
        return;
    ...
    ...
}
```

So, it means that if you set a `null` as a bitmap, this method won't be executed, and the old bitmap still will be drawn. My suggest will be just to hide the view, using `circleImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` or `circleImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`; if you want the view to take up a space for layout proposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this..


class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public ChimmerRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public ChimmerRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float radius = 90.0f; // angle of round corners
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I had some issues but I was getting cast exceptions. But I want to stick to CircularImageView as it is used in my other parts of the code as well and has been tested.

Comment: Can you please tell me you requirement and the exception you get

Answer (score 0):

In your `onBindViewHolder()` of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` if your bitmap is null then create one bitmap with empty or default image then set it to `CircularImageVeiw`

```
   if(bitmap==null){
        //Creating empty bitmap
        bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
   viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way on how to clear image in CircularImageView but could find why the StackOverflowException. I was using Picasso as caching library which 'does not clear' cache. So moved to UniversalImageLoader which works fine and no OutOfMemoryException or StackOverflowException.

If you want to stick to Picasso then you may want to add code to clear cache. This linke helps ->
[Clear Cache memory of Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502659/clear-cache-memory-of-picasso)