# Release all memory from Picasso's cache

Tags: android, android-fragments, caching, picasso

I have a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with a bunch of `Fragment`s that are loaded and destroyed as the user swipes around.  The `Fragment`s each contain some text, and some very large images.  I'm using Picasso to load and cache the images, and each Fragment has its own single instance of Picasso, which is shutdown in `onDestroy()`.

When `onDestroy()` is called for each Fragment, I'd also like to totally clear the memory cache associated with the Picasso instance.  I've tried creating a `PicassoTools` class like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso/23544650#23544650) says, and while that empties the cache (according to the debugger,) it doesn't seem to release the memory associated with the cache, according to the memory monitor.  Here's my code for `onDestroy()`:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        PicassoTools.clearCache(picasso);
        //release cache memory here somehow
        picasso.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**After I clear the cache, how can I totally release all the memory associated with it?**

**UPDATE**:  Here's my PicassoTools.clearCache() method, which is called `onDestroy()`.  I added Bitmap `recycle()`ing, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

```
public static void clearCache(Picasso p) {
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    keys.addAll(((LoopableLruCache) p.cache).keySet()); //LoopableLruCache is an extension of Picasso's LruCache, just with a keySet() method for looping through it easier
    for (String key : keys) {
        Bitmap bmp = p.cache.get(key);
        if (!bmp.isRecycled()) {
            bmp.recycle();
        }
        bmp = null;
        p.invalidate(key);
    }
    p.cache.clear();
}
```

Comment: This should be a similar connection to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502659/clear-cache-memory-of-picasso

Comment: @Xzuing -- thanks, I hadn't thought of recycle()'ing the Bitmaps.  I'm still not making any progress though.