# How to clear Particular Picasso Image cache in android

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso

I am loading image using picasso. In this image, i drawing the paint, after i paint and save the image, but cache image not displayed that drawing line but full image display with drawing lines. But i close the app and again open the app, it cache image display with draw line.

Please suggested me. i am using this picasso. `https://github.com/square/picasso`

Comment: Check here to see if the answer helps you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016382/invalidate-cache-in-picasso

Comment: @ Tasos invalidate is not working, the image still remains in disk cache

Comment: theres another solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453106/clear-disk-sd-card-cache-of-androids-picasso-image-library

Comment: @ Tasos, thanks but i cannot download image from server, i load from sdcard. I debug the code, but cache folder is not available there. What can i do any other solution.

Comment: not sure, but their is some documentation here to have a look -- http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Call `Picasso.invalidate(...)` when you save the image, passing the same path that you used to load the image.

Copying Jake's comment from https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1273