# Android: Heavy recyclerview Bitmap

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bitmap, picasso, bitmapfactory

My app loads alot of images as Mainscreen has recyclerview with images, and once user click on any item it would load more images in a new activity with it's own recyclerview.

now cuz of these images my app ram usage is over 300mb.

so i was wondering is it possible to clear bitmap when activity close?
image follow to show amount of bitmap, i am using Picasso to load images.

```
Picasso.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
```

seems not making much difference at all

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453106/clear-disk-sd-card-cache-of-androids-picasso-image-library?

Comment: all links inside are dead