# android picasso Image dowloading

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I have activity in which there is a dialog window with some images. I want to download these images into cache when my activity starts and load them from cache when dialog window appears.

My activity code:

```
for(int i=0; i<avataritemlist.size();i++){

                Picasso.with(activity_context)
                        .load(item.getpath())
                        .noFade();

            }
```

Dialog adapter code:

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(item.getpath())
            .noFade()
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

I expect to cache the image in my activty and then in dialog adapter load in from cache, but in my case it downloads it again in adapter. I want to emphasize that `activity_context` and `mContext` is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use ImageLoader which will help to maintain cache and load images from cache for more info refer : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html  <br>https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Comment: But it is for volley library, I am using Picasso

Comment: sorry my mistake for posting one link...I have added a link on cachin image as well...

Answer (score 0):

Default Picasso instance returned by [Picasso.with](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#with-android.content.Context-) uses an automatic `memory` and `disk caching`. It is initialized with default values:

```
 •  LRU memory cache of 15% the available application RAM   

 •  Disk cache of 2% storage space up to 50MB but no less than 5MB. (Note: this is only available on API 14+ or if you are using a standalone library that provides a disk cache on all API levels like OkHttp)

 •  Three download threads for disk and network access.
```

How default Picasso instance does LRU memory cache is something you might not be able to know, all you know is `it is a memory cache which uses a least-recently used eviction policy`.

However you can create a Picasso instance using [Picasso.Builder](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/LruCache.html) that gives you a better control over image caching (over disk). Check more on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/using-disk-caching-in-picasso-android-lib) on how to set up http request header property Cache-Control with max-age and [Jake Wharton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944773/how-to-implement-my-own-disk-cache-with-picasso-library-android?lq=1) too

Also you may also want to try out [Glide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) which syntactically is very similar to Picasso