# Why Picasso is not saving image in cache for offline use?

Tags: android, picasso

I have following code, which doesnot load image offline as intended. It works online well but I need to load image offline too. I have given permission for Writing external storage too. Any idea will be really helpful.

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(userInfo.getUserPictureUri())
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
    .resize(80, 80)
    .error(R.drawable.profile_picture)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView_ProfilePictureSide, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            // Try again if cache failed
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                 .load(userInfo.getUserPictureUri())
                 .error(R.drawable.profile_picture)
                 .into(imageView_ProfilePictureSide);
        }
    });
```

Comment: the data is coming from a GET request ?

Comment: which data? ya , Image Url is get request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso

Comment: DO you added compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'  in your gradle file?

Comment: **Try removing that network policy ** as per the docs `Forces the request through the disk cache only, skipping network`.

Comment: Thanks @KingofMasses it worked after adding okhttp. If you can then please post that as answer with reason why picasso needs okhttp. I will accept it. It will be really helpful for others too. :)

Comment: Happy to hear that @BinodLama , Just posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the OkHttp to the gradle build file of the app module :

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
```

Picasso use the `HTTP` client request to `Disk Cache` operation So you can make your own http request header has property `Cache-Control` with `max-age` And create your own Static Picasso Instance instead of default Picasso By using `Okhttp`.

Both the `Okhttp` and `picasso` libraries are provided by squareup team.

References: [How do I use disk caching in Picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso) and  [Github issue about disk cache](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/237), two Questions has been answered by @jake-wharton -> [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944773/how-to-implement-my-own-disk-cache-with-picasso-library-android) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280242/using-picasso-with-custom-disk-cache)